# Recommended Laravel ownership/permissions and deployment

Tags: git, laravel, apache, npm, composer-php

I've been wondering about this for a while now, and I wanted to get some advice on the most recommended permissions and ownership of each. I've read a few guides on this which recommend that either apache/www-data user should be the owner, others which state that only the writable folders should be owned by apache/www-data.

I've seen in guides that this should be the right permissions/ownership. Generally 755 for folders and 644 for files. So assuming this, would that mean the rest of the files would be owned by the deploy/current user? Ideally I would like to set it up so it's easily deployed by a script or Gitlab CI.

```
sudo chgrp -R www-data storage bootstrap/cache
sudo chmod -R ug+rwx storage bootstrap/cache
```

Folders with permissions set to 775:

```
vendor/*
storage/*
bootstrap/*
```

A typical Laravel project will use composer and NPM, and GIT as a repository. So in the case where 'apache' is our apache user, this is what I'm doing currently:

- sudo -Hu apache git pull
- sudo -Hu composer install --no-dev
- sudo -Hu npm install
- sudo -Hu npm run prod

The other way I've done this is, as deploy user ($USER):

- chown -R $USER:$USER /path/to/project/
- git pull
- composer install
- npm install
- npm run prod
- chown -R apache:apache /path/to/project/

Which would be the most recommended approach, in term of both security and ease of deployment?

Also, I have an issue when running composer as

```
sudo -Hu apache composer install --no-dev
```

I get the error:

Cannot create cache directory /opt/rh/httpd24/root/usr/share/httpd/.composer/cache/repo/https---packagist.org/, or directory is not writable. Proceeding without cache

Lastly, I've encountered errors in running npm install at times. Possibly due to installing it using the -g (global flag).

Comment: Could anyone help here? :)